# Помогите с регулярным выражением php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброй ночи, имею выражение

```
$string='ГОСТ Р ИСО /МЭК 7498-1-99. Информационная технология. Взаимосвязь 
открытых систем. Базовая эталонная модель. Часть 1. Базовая модель (принят и 
введен в действие Постановлением Госстандарта России от 18.03.1999 № 78)';
preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+(\W|\W+)\w+\W\d+\W\d+\W\d+~iu",$string,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Получаю ответ:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "ГОСТ Р ИСО /МЭК 7498-1-99" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " /" } }
```

Помогите понять, откуда берётся второй элемент массива " /". Или подскажите как сделать так, чтобы он находил подстроки `ГОСТ Р ИСО /МЭК 7498-1-99` и `ГОСТ Р ИСО/МЭК 7498-1-99`

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Какие переменные в строке? Что постоянно, что меняется? Всегда ли начинается строка именно с "ГОСТ"? Приведите, может быть, пару примеров, какой может быть строка?

Comment: [`~ГОСТ.+\d+~`](https://regex101.com/r/zAxsuj/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `(\W|\W+)` является *захватывающей подмаской*, значение которой при совпадении сохраняется в отдельном буфере (поэтому и присутствует в результате), и означает следующее:

- Проверяет текущий символ, который должен быть отличным от буквы, цифры и знака подчёркивания
- Если находит соответствие, сохраняет его в первой захватывающий подмаске и переходит к проверке следующих шаблонов в выражении
- Если соответствия нет, пытается "захватить" 1 и более символов, которые должны быть отличными от буквы, цифры и знака подчёркивания.

В общем случае, чтобы сделать подмаску незахватываемой, можно добавить `?:` после `(`: `(?:шаблон1|шаблон2)`.

В данном случае, чередование и подмаску можно опустить и использовать только `\W+`.

```
'~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+\W+\w+\W\d+\W\d+\W\d+~ui'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/zAxsuj/1).

Возможно, имеет смысл добавить `+` (1 и более повторов) после каждого `\W`:

```
'~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+\W+\w+\W+\d+\W+\d+\W+\d+~ui'
```

Answer (score 1):

Второй элемент берется в этой строчке: `(\W|\W+)`, т.к. они взяты в скобки. Чтобы их игнорировать, нам достаточно написать `?:`

```
preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+(?:\W|\W+)\w+\W\d+\W\d+\W\d+~iu",$string,$matches);
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы он искал вот так
preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+\W\w+\W\d+\W\d+\W\d+~iu",$string,$matches);
и вот так тоже
preg_match_all("~ГОСТ\s*Р\s*\w+\W+\w+\W\d+\W\d+\W\d+~iu",$string,$matches);
Разница только в одном месте. \W и \W+